# what is the singularity at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Could any one tell me what is the singularity at $z=0$ of $f(z)=\sin \large({1\over \cos({1\over z})})$?

I know that at $z=0$ $\cos ({1\over z})$ got an essential singularity. I am not able to put it rigorously but I think $f$ too have essential singularity at $z=0$

Thank you.

Comment: Since this function has infinitely many essential singularities in any neighbourhood of $0$ (namely at all zeros of $\cos(1/z)$), I don't see how $z=0$ could *not* be an essential singularity.

Comment: @celtschk could you do it elaborately by Casorati Weirstrass or Laurenge Series explanation?

Comment: As far as I can see, the preconditions of Casorati-Weierstrass cannot be fulfilled near $z=0$, therefore the theorem is not applicable. I assume with "Laurenge series" you mean "Laurent series", but I'm not sure you can express this function as Laurent series around $z=0$ either (I suspect not). Actually, I think that a proof that you cannot express it as Laurent series around $z=0$ should also be a proof that it is an essential singularity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singularity at $z=0$ is not isolated. The usual classification of removable singularities, poles and essential singularitites are almost always reserved for isolated singularities.

Comment: so the singulairity is essential right?